# iPhone: Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using Default?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keypad

I'm writing an iPhone app which uses a keypad that includes a decimal point. Because this is not standard in the Interface Builder i have assigned this to a text field in the `viewDidLoad` method like this:

```
[self.TextField_PrintedRepeat setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];
```

When i run this app, tap the text field and expose the keypad, i get this entered into the console log:

> Can't find keyplane that supports type
>   8 for keyboard
>   iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using
>   Default

Have you any ideas what this means?
Do i need to worry?
How can i stop this console message?

EDIT: i'm using iOS 4.2.1

Comment: The console message is benign and happens on at least 4.3.  I've reported this as a bug (ID# 9295924) but I suspect I'm not the first to do so.

Comment: This really annoys me.. it doesn't matter but it's still really annoying! - Thanks for reporting it :)

Comment: i'm also using 4.3.1 and get this warnings. Its a bit confusion but i just leave the message and that it. Bye Alex

Comment: I'd the same problem with iOS 7.1.1

Comment: This is still showing for iOS 14 ;(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version OS are you running against? the DecimalPad keyboard type was only introduced in 4.1, so if you are planning on allowing prior versions you will get this warning, and it will revert to the normal keyboard type. If you don't want this happening, check for the existence of UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad before doing the call.

Comment: @owen gerig: same here. But when I choose an other keyboard than the decimal one, everything is fine.

Comment: `UIKeyboardTypePhonePad` also has the same warning showing